# How can I list subdirectories recursively for HDFS?

Tags: list, hadoop, find, hdfs

I have a set of directories created in HDFS recursively. How can list all the directories ? For a normal unix file system I can do that using the below command

```
find /path/ -type d -print
```

But I want to get the similar thing for HDFS.

Comment: Useful question, but I would like to know the size of directories, to better replicate du functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To list directory contents recursively `hadoop dfs -lsr /dirname` command can be used.

To filter only directories , you can `grep` "drwx" (since owner has rwx permission on directories) in output of above command.

Hence whole command will look like as below.

```
$hadoop dfs -lsr /sqoopO7 | grep drwx
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer given by @Shubhangi Pardeshi is correct but for latest hadoop version command has deprecated. So new latest command can be used as below

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /user | grep drwx
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method should be more robust to only get directories because it depends less on the permissions.

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /folder | grep "^d"
```