# Get a list of subdirectories

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, bigdata

I know I can do this:

```
data = sc.textFile('/hadoop_foo/a')
data.count()
240
data = sc.textFile('/hadoop_foo/*')
data.count()
168129
```

However, I would like to count the size of the data of every subdirectory of "/hadoop_foo/". Can I do that?

In other words, what I want is something like this:

```
subdirectories = magicFunction()
for subdir in subdirectories:
  data sc.textFile(subdir)
  data.count()
```

---

I tried with:

```
In [9]: [x[0] for x in os.walk("/hadoop_foo/")]
Out[9]: []
```

but I think that fails, because it searches at the local directory of the driver (the gateway in that case), while "/hadoop_foo/" lies in the [hdfs](/questions/tagged/hdfs). Same for "hdfs:///hadoop_foo/".

---

After reading [How can I list subdirectories recursively for HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056680/how-can-i-list-subdirectories-recursively-for-hdfs), I am wondering if there is a way to execute:

```
hadoop dfs -lsr /hadoop_foo/
```

in code..

---

From [Correct way of writing two floats into a regular txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303218/correct-way-of-writing-two-floats-into-a-regular-txt):

```
In [28]: os.getcwd()
Out[28]: '/homes/gsamaras'  <-- which is my local directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With python use [hdfs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdfs/) module; [walk()](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hdfs.client.Client.walk) method can get you list of files.

The code sould look something like this:

```
from hdfs import InsecureClient

client = InsecureClient('http://host:port', user='user')
for stuff in client.walk(dir, 0, True):
...
```

With Scala you can get the filesystem (`val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())`) and run https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listFiles(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path, boolean)

You can also execute a shell command from your script with [os.subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) but this is never a recommended approach since you depend on text output of a shell utility here.

---

Eventually, what worked for the OP was using [subprocess.check_output()](/hadoop_foo/):

```
subdirectories = subprocess.check_output(["hadoop","fs","-ls", "/hadoop_foo/"])
```

Comment: Is this [tag:java] or [tag:python]? I am using [tag:python]. Also it's not clear what follows run, a link? I mean what I exactly should I do in my code? `subprocess.call(["/hadoop_foo/"])` says it cannot find main class `dfs`. Same with `fs` in place of `dfs`. I also tried "hadoop dfs" in the 1st part, and got `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Edited the answer to provide python way of getting files recursively.

Comment: I saw it, thank you. `No module named hdfs`, I am doomed.. '_', but +1 for providing options! If you want upvote the question to bring more people here, that may be able to help! :)

Comment: re os.subprocess.call() ; can you try hdfs dfs -lsr command, not hadoop dfs? subprocess.call(["hdfs","dfs","-lsr", directory])

Comment: WOW, it actually listed the directories! However, this listed and the part-xxxxx files of Spark, i.e. "/hadoop_foo/a/part-00000" and so on, any idea to get only "/hadoop_foo/a/", "/hadoop_foo/b/" and so on? If not that's okay, just let me know though! :) Oh, just remove the `r`! ;) Update the answer so that I can accept! :D But do you know how I can use them? If I do `subdirectories = subprocess.call(["hdfs","dfs","-ls", /hadoop_foo/])`, the `subdirectories` will be empty, and the subdirectories will be printed, instead of getting assigned into the list..

Comment: No "directories only" options for hdfs dfs -lsr; when in shell people grep by 'drwx' afterwards; with python, I would grab all lines and then filter.
If you can install python's hdfs module; there's more luck with it (walk() function returns iterator on paths among others).

Comment: I cannot install anything, no rights at all. As I updated, you can do that with `-ls`, instead of `-lsr`. So now the only thing is how to store that output and then loop over it, so that I can read the RDD in every loop and count it!

Comment: subprocess.check_output() to have stdout returned.