# Find substring between / and \

Tags: python, linux, string, apache-spark, substring

After [Get a list of subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420685/get-a-list-of-subdirectories), I got strings of that form:

```
In [30]: print(subdir)
 foousa          0 2016-09-07 19:58 /projects/foousa/obama/trump/10973689-Parthenon
drwx------   -
```

and when I try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3368991/2411320):

```
In [23]: print find_between( subdir, "/", "\\" )


In [24]: print find_between( subdir, "\/", "\\" )
```

I don't get anything, maybe a newline only... What I was aiming for is `10973689-Parthenon`.

What am I missing?

I am using [spark](/questions/tagged/spark), but I couldn't see how this would matter...

Comment: \n is the new line character.  There may not be a \ in that string.  I'm guessing that it is just printing an empty string.

Comment: @RobertPrévost correct, but I don't get what you say. `subdir` is what I showed above, and `10973689-Parthenon` is what I want to extract.

Comment: Try executing print(subdir) or subdir.index('\n').  I'm getting at find_between_r(subdir, '/', '\n').

Comment: The first gives me exactly the string I have in the question as input and the second 87.

Comment: are you sure your text actually contains `\ ` ? not just `\n` ?

Comment: njzk2, I think I know where the confusion comes from, let me update. @RobertPrévost check the update, now I understood what you were asking! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using `re`**:

```
import re

subdir = ' foousa          0 2016-09-07 19:58 /projects/foousa/obama/trump/10973689-Parthenon\ndrwx------   - '
match = re.search(r'/([^/\n]+)\n', subdir)
print(match.group(1))
```

**Using indexes:**

```
subdir = ' foousa          0 2016-09-07 19:58 /projects/foousa/obama/trump/10973689-Parthenon\ndrwx------   - '
begin = subdir.rindex('/') + 1
end = subdir.rindex('\n')
result = subdir[begin:end]
print(result)
```

output:

```
10973689-Parthenon
```

Comment: Are you sure? I am getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

Comment: then are you really sure that '\n' isnt actually newline? relpace '\\' in regex to '\n' and try again.

Comment: It should have been an actual newline, if you read the first question I linked to. Where exactly? You have `\\` twice and you didn't explain the regex, and I do not know about them.. :/

Comment: `re.search(r'/([^/\\]+)\\', subdir)` -> `re.search(r'/([^/\n]+)\n', subdir)`

Comment: Check my updated question and now you probably will know why your last comment didn't work either!

Comment: Try second option. And if it doesnt work give output of result.